# have RelationID on both sides of OneToOne relation typeorm postgres

Tags: postgresql, typeorm, one-to-one

I have user and profile entities and they have a onetoone relation together.
I am using typeorm and postgres
I used joincolumn on user and have access to RelationId (or Column) profileId on user side
However I want to have userId on profile side as well
How can I accomplish this?

something like this:

```js
export class User extends BaseEntity {

@OneToOne(()=>Profile)
profile:number

@Column()
profileId:number

}

////////

export class Profile extends BaseEntity{

@OneToOne(()=>Profile)
user: number

@Column()
userId: number

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You may find answer in documantation.

Relations can be uni-directional and bi-directional. Uni-directional are relations with a relation decorator only on one side. Bi-directional are relations with decorators on both sides of a relation.

@JoinColumn must only be on one side of the relation - on the table that will own the foreign key.

```
import {User} from "./User";

@Entity()
export class Profile {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    gender: string;

    @Column()
    photo: string;

    @OneToOne(type => User, user => user.profile) // specify inverse side as a second parameter
    user: User;

}

import {Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, OneToOne, JoinColumn} from "typeorm";
import {Profile} from "./Profile";

@Entity()
export class User {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @OneToOne(type => Profile, profile => profile.user) // specify inverse side as a second parameter
    @JoinColumn()
    profile: Profile;

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. In one to one relation, the relation Id is only stored on the table with joinColumn in it. I wanted to have the realtionId of each on both sides. 
In the current situation, I will only have profileId on user entity. I want to also have the userId on the profile entity. I am using graphql and I need to query on user withoput having to query the profile first.

Comment: You may use something like this `this.profileRepository.findOne({ where: { profileId: 1}, relations: ['user']})` and then describe graphQlL ObjectType DTO where will be profile and user.Or maybe you should read documentation https://doug-martin.github.io/nestjs-query/  and use Relation/FiltarebleRelation decorators

Comment: Thank you, this seems like a great alternative. I will give it a try.